# How to solve the rippled NotConnectedError?

Tags: blockchain, ripple

I installed rippled and started the service by using `sudo systemctl start rippled`.
When checking the status of rippled, it is working.
But I can't connect to the server in node.js.
I tried like below.

```
var RippleAPI = require('ripple-lib').RippleAPI;

var rippleAPI= new RippleAPI({
    server: 'wss://localhost:5005'
});

rippleAPI.on('error', (errorCode, errorMessage) => {
    console.log(errorCode + ': ' + errorMessage);
});
rippleAPI.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('connected');
});
rippleAPI.on('disconnected', (code) => {
  // code - [close code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-
  US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent) sent by the server
  // will be 1000 if this was normal closure
  console.log('disconnected, code:', code);
});

rippleAPI.connect().then(() => {

}).then(() => {
  return rippleAPI.disconnect();
}).catch(console.error);
```

When I start the node, it says `NotConnectedError(socket hang up)`.
How can I connect?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've enabled `wss` in your `rippled.cfg`. It is commented out by default.

Otherwise rippled sometimes looks like it's running even when the `server_state` indicates `full`. And when you try `ledger current` it returns `"error_code":17` `InsufficientNetworkMode`. In this case all you can do is wait.

Maybe your server doesn't have the enough resources. Check out their [documentation](https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/). They've recently updated it and it's even more easier to setup a rippled server now.